# Declaring a type for an object where its keys discriminate value types from array union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I believe it is the best to illustrate that in a clear example:

```
enum EventType { A, B, C };

type MyEvent =
  [EventType.A, number] |
  [EventType.B, string] |
  [EventType.C, number, string];

const eventsGrouped: Record<EventType, MyEvent[]> = {
  [EventType.A]: [],
  [EventType.B]: [],
  [EventType.C]: [],
};
```

The goal is to create a type for `eventsGrouped` object
that discriminates value type based on the key

In pseudocode:

```
Record<EventType, MyEvent where MyEvent[0] === object entry key>
```

So that:

- `eventsGrouped[EventType.A]` is of type `[EventType.A, number]`
- `eventsGrouped[EventType.B]` is of type `[EventType.B, string]`
- `eventsGrouped[EventType.C]` is of type `[EventType.C, number, string]`

Comment: "that discriminates value type based on the key" Do you actually mean "that discriminates array element type based on the key"? In which case, what would the array element type for `EventType.C` be?

Comment: The type for `[EventType.C]` would be `[EventType.C, number, string]`, the same behavior when type narrowing: `if (myEvent[0] === EventType.C)`

Comment: So you would like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NB4pzW)?

Comment: Or [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgFQJ4AdhQN5QIIA0UAQkQMJQC+AUNYhlgLKrxJQC81UUA2qyCgYA6QlHAQARsABOAXSgAfLr36DMQ0lADOiaQEsQAc3lLufBALTqyRcVOlEd+o7IDctepijNVVrOxxlM19hPFkALhULNWARW0h7WQIgqKQ-DQjUy2FNJwNjZO5g6PSyTPM04RsxBJlHXXzZahpqAGMAexAdKGBorQBxaXawTAATSIAlYA7pUYAeEMwiHxKGCuzMWQA+DkDiyvUwyJ4UxdjCFIBGS+Uk5XWYjOOzjSIAImI3u-2N2LLn1bWd5kL7JSjuahAA), if you like things messy ;).

Comment: That type is termed a "tuple" in TypeScript, by the way. An array with a specified number of elements of given types. Might make further research more fruitful.

Comment: yes! that's it, thank you, you can post this as answer so I can accept it if you want

Comment: I'll use @vera. 's solution, defining MyEventType as you did was a solution I thought of, but yeah, it is messy and would be a hassle when dealing with 20+ event types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple with [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) introduced in version 4.1:

```
type EventsGrouped = { [T in MyEvent as T[0]]: T };
```

It's a little hard to digest at first, but we are "looping" over the union, and for each member of the union, we use `T[0]` as the *key*, and `T` as the *value*.

Then you can use this as the type for `eventsGrouped`:

```
const eventsGrouped: EventsGrouped = {
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NB4pzW)

---

Pre 4.1, still possible with mapped types! It needs extra work because you need to manually extract the corresponding member back out:

```
type EventsGrouped = { [K in MyEvent[0]]: Extract<MyEvent, [K, ...any[]]> };
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mp84gm)